# Download all AWS Lambda functions using Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I want to download all my Lambda functions to my computer or S3 using Lambda running Nodejs.

I have have found this code that uses python and the AWS CLI to do it but i don't know any Python: https://gist.github.com/nemaniarjun/defdde356b6678352bcd4af69b7fe529

```
download_code () {
    local OUTPUT=$1
    aws lambda get-function --function-name $OUTPUT --query 'Code.Location' | xargs wget -O ./lambda_functions/$OUTPUT.zip   }

mkdir -p lambda_functions

for run in $(aws lambda list-functions | cut -f 6 | xargs); do  download_code "$run" & done

echo "Completed Downloading all the Lamdba Functions!"
```

Some help in how to convert to Node would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not Python, that's a bash shell script.

Comment: You need to look into https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#getFunction-property to download a function, note how it says "with a link to download the deployment package that's valid for 10 minutes". And you need to use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listFunctions-property to get a list of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark B gave a good answer, thank you

> You need to look into https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#getFunction-property to download a function, note how it says "with a link to download the deployment package that's valid for 10 minutes". And you need to use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listFunctions-property to get a list of functions.

This is what i built to get download urls for all functions and then make Lambda download them to S3:

```
var request = require('request');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-north-1' });
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({ region: 'eu-north-1' });
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

var result = [];
var counter = 0;

var params = {
    MaxItems: 100
};

lambda.listFunctions(params, function (err, lambdaFunctions) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else {

        // We got the functions now lets get the urls
        lambdaFunctions.Functions.forEach(LambdaFunc => {

            var params = {
                FunctionName: LambdaFunc.FunctionName
            };

            lambda.getFunction(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else {


                    var temp = { Code: data.Code, Configuration: data.Configuration };
                    result.push(temp);

                    counter++;
                    if (counter == lambdaFunctions.Functions.length) {

                        downloadToS3();

                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
});

function downloadToS3() {

    result.forEach(data => {

        var FunctionName = data.Configuration.FunctionName;
        console.log(FunctionName);
        var path = "lambda/" + FunctionName + ".zip";
        var bucket = "YOUR-BUCKET-NAME";

        var Location = data.Code.Location;
        var options = {
            uri: Location,
            encoding: null
        };
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
                console.log("failed to download function");
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log(FunctionName + " " + Location);
                s3.putObject({
                    Body: body,
                    Key: path,
                    Bucket: bucket
                }, function (error, data) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log("!! error downloading func to s3 !!");
                        callback("Error downloading func: " + FunctionName);
                    } else {
                        console.log("success uploading " + FunctionName + " to s3");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
};
```

Dont forget to give this Lamda function all the rights it needs to list other Lambda functions and upload (put) to S3. Or else it will fail.